# What makes for a Balanced State of Capital?

Tags: pattern

If the capital city of a US state conforms to a special rule, I identify it as having a Balanced State of Capital™. As it turns out, only 8 of the 50 state capitals qualify for this Balanced State.

Those 8 state capitals, in alphabetical order, are:

- Atlanta, GA
- Boise, ID
- Juneau, AK
- Nashville, TN
- Phoenix, AZ
- Richmond, VA
- Sacramento, CA
- Topeka, KS

What rule defines these each as Balanced State of Capitals?

Hint 1:

> There are 42 state capitals that don't qualify. Look at a few to see how they might differ from these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A capital city has a Balanced State of Capital if

> it has the same number of letters in its name as its respective state.